# find the x-intercept of a natural logarithm function with a power of 2

Tags: logarithms

find the $x$-intercept of the function $y = \ln((3x-2)^2)$.

in order to find it, move the power 2 in front of the natural log: $y = 2 \ln(3x-2)$.

for x -intercept, $y = 0$. Therefore, $\ln(3x-2) = 0$. Hence, $(3x-2) = 1$. and x = 1.

The question is why cannot set $(3x-2)^2 = 1$. This give an additional answer ($x = 1/3$), which is wrong. Why?

Answer (score 1):

We have $y=\ln(3x-2)^2$, since by the power of logs we can bring the power down as a coefficient of the log we get $y=2\ln(3x-2)$. For a $x$-intercept we have $y=0$ so $2\ln(3x-2)=0$, then $\ln(3x-2)=0$.

Next we can take the exponentials of each side:

$$e^{ln(3x-2)}=e^0$$

$$3x-2=1 \rightarrow x=1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$y=2\ln|3x-2|=0$$ so $$\ln|3x-2|=\ln(1)$$ so you have to solve  $$|3x-2|=1$$

Comment: if there is the modulus (absolute) sign, would 1/3 be the answer too?

Comment: For $$\ln(x^{1/3})$$ we nead no absolute signs, if we define $$x>0$$

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry. I am just a bit confused. Can x =  -1 negative number for y = ln x^2?

Comment: Yes it nis $$\ln((-1)^2)=\ln(1)=0$$

Comment: is it correct to say if x stand by itself like ln x^2, you can find the square of the x first.  For a function like 3x -2 in ln (3x -2)^2, you have to move the 2 in front of ln first.

Comment: This is correct what you stated.

Comment: We have $$\ln(x^r)=r\ln(x)$$ for $$x>0$$

Comment: thanks so much for explaining and patient.

Comment: This is ok, i hope your problem is solved now.